# How to programmatically find all of the file locations of an external table in Hive?

Tags: hive, hiveql

I have some external tables in Hive and want to write a script that will tweak the data in them. Since Hive is the source of truth for what files it reads, I want to get the locations for the partitions from it.

Is there a convenient syntax to get a list of the locations for all partitions for an external table?

Answer (score 0):

The describe command will do it:

```
DESCRIBE FORMATTED Db_name.table_name
```

Comment: That only shows the configured default location for the table. Since I have external partitions, my table has files in other directories (and files in its default location that are not part of the table).

Comment: You can sync the meta data for the table if files/partitions are changed: MSCK REPAIR TABLE table_name SYNC PARTITIONS;

Answer (score 0):

If you have access to `hive metastore`, you can get details via query under script/program:

E.g. query on hive metastore:

```
SELECT d.NAME, a.tbl_name, b.location, c.PART_NAME 
FROM dbs d 
inner join tbls a ON d.DB_ID = a.db_id 
inner JOIN sds b ON a.SD_ID = b.sd_id 
LEFT outer JOIN partitions c ON a.TBL_ID = c.tbl_id 
WHERE a.tbl_name = 'your_table_name' AND d.name = 'your_db_name'
```